What does it means when the dashboard of Channels (1-3) turns red?
While using Unetstack, I suddenly noticed that the Channel(1-3) interface on the localhost web page turned red. What could be the problem?
Here is the image:


This generally means those are disable, what parameter did you change ?

I just adjusted the baseband sampling rate to 16 kHz.

The default PHY in UnetStack needs baseband sampling rate to be numerically equal to the carrier frequency
